# Linear Interpolation C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, numerical-methods

I have to write a collection of methods for performing linear, bilinear and trilinear interpolation. I have also to write some tests to show that interpolation is exact for polynomials (which should be the case using these interpolation methods).

I ended up writing  the following classes as core for my interpolation

[Here one-second  compile/run github repo (gtest required)](https://github.com/knotman90/linear_interpolation).

```
#ifndef LINEARINTERPOLATE_H
#define LINEARINTERPOLATE_H

#include<assert.h>

namespace FL{

typedef unsigned int uint;

template< int DIM, typename T = long double>
struct point{
    T coords [DIM] ;
    T val;

    inline const T coord(const int c) const{
        assert(c >= 0  && c < DIM);
        return coords[c];
    }
};


template <class T>
class LinearInterpolator{

public:

 /*
      y
      ^         p1
      |        /
      |       /
      |      /
      |     p
      |    /
      |   p0
      |
      |
      o-------------------------> x

  */
    /*  P: point the lie between a and b
     *  a,b boundary of the 1D cuboid, a<=b
     */
      point<1,T>& Linear (  point<1,T>& p , const   point<1,T>&a, const   point<1,T>&b, int c=0  ){
        T x_d = (p.coord(c)-a.coord(c)) * (1/(b.coord(c) - a.coord(c)));
        p.val = Linear(a.val,b.val,x_d);
        return p;
    }

    /*  P: point the lie inside the cuboid defined by the first two values of v
     *     v[0] <= v[1]
     */
      point<1,T>& Linear (  point<1,T>& p , const   point<1,T>* v , int c=0  ){
        T x_d = (p.coord(c)-v[0].coord(c)) * (1/(v[1].coord(c) - v[0].coord(c)));
        p.val = Linear(v[0].val,v[1].val,x_d);
        return p;
    }

/*----------------BILINEAR------------------------
           y
           ^
           |   p2.......p3
           |   .        .
           |   .        .
           |   .        .
           |   .        .
           |   p0.......p1
           |
           |
           o-------------------------> x

 p point that lie in the cuboid defined by the 4 values array v
-------------------------------------------------*/

      point<2,T>& Bilinear ( point<2,T>& p , const  point<2,T>*v  ){
        T x_d = (p.coord(0)-v[0].coord(0)) * (1/(v[1].coord(0) - v[0].coord(0)));
        T y_d = (p.coord(1)-v[0].coord(1)) * (1/(v[2].coord(1) - v[0].coord(1)));
        p.val = Bilinear(v[0].val,v[1].val,v[2].val,v[3].val,x_d,y_d);
        return p;
    }



/*----------------TRILINEAR------------------------
 *
              y            p6____________p7
              ^           / |            /|
              |          /  |           / |
              |         /   |          /  |
              |        p2___|_________p3  |
              |        |    |         |   |
              |        |   p4_________|__p5
              |        |   /          |  /
              |        |  /           | /
              |        | /            |/
              |        p0_____________p1
              |
              |-------------------------> x
              /
             /
            /
           /
          /
        z/


        p point that lie in the cuboid defined by the 8 values array v
-------------------------------------------------*/

      point<3,T>& Trilinear ( point<3,T>& p , const   point<3,T>*v ){
        T x_d = (p.coord(0)-v[0].coord(0)) * (1/(v[1].coord(0) - v[0].coord(0)));
        T y_d = (p.coord(1)-v[0].coord(1)) * (1/(v[2].coord(1) - v[0].coord(1)));
        T z_d = (p.coord(2)-v[0].coord(2)) * (1/(v[4].coord(2) - v[0].coord(2)));
        p.val =Trilinear(v[0].val,v[1].val,v[2].val,v[3].val,v[4].val,v[5].val,v[6].val,v[7].val,
                x_d,y_d,z_d);

        return p;
    }



private:
    inline T Linear(const T f0, const  T f1, const  T xd){
        //return std::fma(f0, (1-xd) , f1*xd);
        return f0*(1.0-xd) + f1*xd;
    }

    inline T Bilinear(const T f00,const   T f10,const T f01, const T f11, const T xd, const T yd){
        const T c0 = f00*(static_cast<T>(1.0)-xd) + f10*xd;
        const T c1 = f01*(static_cast<T>(1.0)-xd) + f11*xd;
        return Linear(c0,c1,yd);
    }

    inline T Trilinear(const T f000, const T f100,const T f010,const T f110,const T f001, const T f101,const T f011,const  T f111,const  T xd,const  T yd ,const  T zd){
        const T c0 = Bilinear(f000,f100,f010,f110,xd,yd);
        const T c1 = Bilinear(f001,f101,f011,f111,xd,yd);
        return  Linear(c0,c1,zd);
    }
}; //class interpolator

}
#endif /* INTERPOLATE */
```

Everything is working fine and tests shows  that the interpolation is correct for polynomials.

1. #### Could I improve the design of the class someway?
2. #### Is there any better way to do the calculation in order to minimize the rounding errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer to include the C++ header `<cassert>`, to be consistent.  Use the C compatibility headers only in code that must compile with a C compiler.

I don't see the need for the final argument `c` to `Linear()`, given that it's passed to `point<1,T>::coords()`, for which the only valid value is `0`.  Also there's an inaccurate comment there: `a,b boundary of the 1D cuboid, a<=b` - but we need **`a<b`** to avoid division by zero.

I don't see a good reason for creating a reciprocal and multiplying by that, instead of simply dividing.  It appears to me to be unnecessary duplication:

> ```
>    T x_d = (p.coord(c)-a.coord(c)) * (1/(b.coord(c) - a.coord(c)));
> ```

becomes:

```
    T x_d = (p.coord(c)-a.coord(c)) / (b.coord(c) - a.coord(c));
```

We might want to make a helper function for these very similar "portion" computations.

We can make `point::coord()` `constexpr`, and all the members of `LinearInterpolator` can be made both `constexpr` and `static`.

Instead of the `static_cast` of 1.0 to `T`, we might make a simple constant:

```
private:
    static constexpr T unity = 1.0;
```

BTW, a "1D cuboid" is normally called a *line*, and a "2D cuboid" a *rectangle*.